# Find the length of the curve parametrized by $x(\theta) = r(\theta - \sin\theta)$

Tags: calculus

I am really having difficulties in Calculus II and i am trying to do as many examples as i can. I bumped into this question and I dont have any slightest idea where i should start. Help appreciated.

Find the length of the curve parametrized by

$$x(\theta) = r(\theta - \sin\theta)$$ 
$$y(\theta) = r(1 - \cos\theta)$$ and $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

Comment: Is $r$ a constant?

Comment: The length of the curve is given by the integral $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{x'(\theta)^2+y'(\theta)^2}\mathrm{d}\theta$.

Comment: @Nicolas how did you get that? can you show me the method?

Comment: You have in general differentials ds, dx and dy are assumed basically to form a rectangle triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a cycloide.

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{x'(\theta)^2+y'(\theta)^2}\mathrm{d}\theta$ =$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sqrt{r^2(1-cos\theta)^2 + r^2(sin\theta})^2$ = $4r[-cos\theta/2]_0^{2\pi}$ = 8r